# How can i get current height in VueJS with Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I used a Ref to save the current height, of the active element. Now I want to apply the height to the next element that is clicked on.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

defineProps<{
  content: Array<{ title: string; content: string }>;
}>();

const contentRefs = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
const isToggled = reactive<{ value: number | null }>({ value: null });

const handleClick = (index: number) => (isToggled.value = isToggled.value === index ? null : index);
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in content" class="accordion" :class="{ open: isToggled.value === index }" :key="index">
    <div @click="() => handleClick(index)">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div ref="contentRefs" :style="{ minHeight: isToggled.value === index ? contentRefs?.scrollHeight : '0' }">{{ item.content }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am trying to get the current height of the active element from the Ref with `contentRefs?.scrollHeight`
But I do not get my height returned

Comment: contentRefs can't work like that because you're using v-for, and there will be several divs. It's supposed to be an array, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When ref is used inside v-for, the corresponding ref should contain an Array value, which will be populated with the elements after mount:

[Refs inside v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)

Also, you probably want to set `maxHeight` instead of `minHeight`...
Here is your slightly modified code in the example: [**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).